# Analytic Hierarchy Process - consistency ratio over 50%

Tags: ranking

I have such data of pair-wise comparison. I calculated consistency ratio for this data of 56%. That's too high for relevant results.

[image]

Whether is possible to modify initial data to improve consistency if I have no other sources what factor should I fix?

Answer (score 0):

I read some articles and came up to the solution when consistency is very high like 100% I need to reduce it to min 20% by playing with most dismised values.

I recommend online calculator for AHP
https://bpmsg.com/ahp/ahp-calc.php